# AWS Redshift: How to run copy command from Apache NiFi without using firehose?

Tags: amazon-redshift, upsert

I have flow files with data records in it. I'm able to place it on S3 bucket. From there on I want to run COPY command and update command with joins to achieve MERGE / UPSERT operation. Can anyone suggest ways to solve this as firehose only executes copy command and I can't make UPSERT / MERGE operation as prescribed by AWS docs directly, so has to copy into staging table and update or insert using some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this but I usually go with a lambda function run every 5 minutes or so that takes the data put in Redshift from firehose and merges it with existing data.  Redshift likes to run on larger "chunks" of data and it is most efficient if you build up some size before performing these operations.  The best practice is to move the data from the firehose target in an atomic operation like ALTER TABLE APPEND and use this new table as the source for merging.  This is so firehose can keep adding data while the merge is in process.